# How to write Javascript to change CSS of even rows

Tags: javascript, gridview

I want to highlight/change the CSS of all even rows of gridview using Javascript.
How could it be possible?

(Its only through JavaScript and not jQuery or grid theme)

Answer (score 3):

How about some CSS:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: red}
```

Comment: it will be dynamic to change of css. not want to apply css statically. your css is fine but , i need to change it using javascrpt for gridview row.

Comment: you could create a class that would have this style then just apply and remove it to the grid as needed, should work the same with much less work for the browser.

Comment: when i do create class as - .gridTR
{        
  tr:nth-child(even) {background: red}        
} then it shows syntax error.. whats wrong here..

Comment: can any one make this css as a class so, it can be apply specifically for a control instead of all tr in the page. ??

Answer (score 0):

you can count the number of rows and if the current row (the counter) is divisible by 2, then it is even, that's when you add the css.

otherwise, use CSS selectors on your stylesheet. "tr:nth-child(even)"